# Send memory variables from Server to Client in open62541

Tags: c, opc-ua, open62541

I'm trying to create a bridge in C Language that uses two protocols : OPC-UA and MODBUS.
Between the client and the bridge I used the protocol open62541 to ask for some data of any type. When the bridge receive the request, the memory requests start, from the brigde with the protocol MODBUS, to the MODBUS server, that should send back those memory variable asked.
My problem is that I cannot find any way to see the point in the code, where the Server recieve the Client request.
I need to find how to send those memory variables back from the server to the Client.
I would be glad if someone has the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not stated clear enough, and you should also provide some info on what you already did or tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By guessing I assume you mean a ReadRequest and you want to find out where this read request is handled in the server?

It could be this one: `Service_Read`

https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/71e9a44d1aec5bc0cce465c8daefe47883b25f6c/src/server/ua_services_attribute.c#L394

Or also the `Operation_Read`:

https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/71e9a44d1aec5bc0cce465c8daefe47883b25f6c/src/server/ua_services_attribute.c#L394

you are looking for?!

Comment: I modified my question, try to read it, maybe, youo can find some other infos non provided before. If not, please, notice it to me. I will immediately try to change it better